# Failing to update certain records in the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Well, for a good while I've now been stuck trying to figure out why most of my records are updating successfully while a certain few aren't. I've checked the php variable name/sql row names, ajax request and I don't see anything wrong. So here I am, hoping that someone can take a look at my code and help me figure out what's wrong.

[Screenshot to show what I'm refering to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cJOc.png)

Html/JS:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>General Reservation
            <small>Update, Delete</small>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Department/Group</th>
                    <th>On-site Contact</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Event Description</th>
                    <th>Setup Time</th>
                    <th>Number of Participants</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Start/End Time</th>
                    <th>Special Accommodations</th>
                    <th>Room</th>
                    <th>Room Style</th>
                    <th>Catering</th>
                    <th>Technical Equipment</th>
                    <th>Pre-Clean</th>
                    <th>On-clean</th>
                    <th>Post-Clean</th>
                    <th>Reserved Parkning</th>
                    <th>VIP</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script>
function viewGenData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "servergen.php",
        success: function(data){
            $('tbody').html(data);
        }
    });
}
function updateGenData(str){
    var id = str;
    var name = $('#name-'+str).val();
    var dptGroup = $('#dptgroup-'+str).val();
    var onSiteContact = $('#onsitecontact-'+str).val();
    var phone = $('#phone-'+str).val();
    var email = $('#email-'+str).val();
    var eventDesc = $('#eventdesc-'+str).val();
    var setUpTime = $('#setuptime-'+str).val();
    var numOfParticipants = $('#partcnum-'+str).val();
    var date = $('#date-'+str).val();
    var startEndTime = $('#startendtime-'+str).val();
    var specialAcc = $('#specialacc-'+str).val();
    var room = $('#room-'+str).val();
    var roomStyle = $('#roomstyle-'+str).val();
    var catering = $('#catering-'+str).val();
    var techEquip = $('#techequip-'+str).val();
    var preClean = $('#preclean-'+str).val();
    var postClean = $('#postclean-'+str).val();
    var onClean = $('#onclean-'+str).val();
    var rsvParking = $('#rsvparking-'+str).val();
    var vip = $('#vip-'+str).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "servergen.php?p=edit",
        data: "name=" + name + "&department=" + dptGroup + "&contact=" + onSiteContact + "&phone=" +
        phone + "&email=" + email + "&description=" + eventDesc + "&setuptime=" + setUpTime + "&numberofparticipants=" + numOfParticipants +
        "&date=" + date + "&startendtime=" + startEndTime + "&specialacc=" + specialAcc + "&room=" + room + "&roomstyle=" + roomStyle +
        "&catering=" + catering + "&techequipment=" + techEquip + "&preclean=" + preClean + "&postclean=" + postClean + "&onclean=" + onClean +
        "&rsvparking=" + rsvParking + "&vip=" + vip + "&id=" + id,
        success: function(data){
            viewGenData();
        }
    });
}
function deleteGenData(str){
    var id = str;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "servergen.php?p=del",
        data: "id="+id,
        success: function(data){
            viewGenData();
        }
    });
}
```

Php/mySQL:

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$page = isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';

if($page=='edit'){

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$dptGroup = $_POST['dptgroup'];
$onSiteContact = $_POST['onsitecontact'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$eventDesc = $_POST['eventdesc'];
$setUpTime = $_POST['setuptime'];
$numOfParticipants = $_POST['partcnum'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$startEndTime = $_POST['startendtime'];
$specialAcc = $_POST['specialacc'];
$room = $_POST['room'];
$roomStyle = $_POST['roomstyle'];
$catering = $_POST['catering'];
$techEquip = $_POST['techequip'];
$preClean = $_POST['preclean'];
$postClean = $_POST['postclean'];
$onClean = $_POST['onclean'];
$rsvParking = $_POST['rsvparking'];
$vip = $_POST['vip'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("update reservations set req_name=?, dept_group=?, onsite_contact=?, phone_num=?, email=?, event_description=?, setup_time=?, num_participants=?, date=?, start_end_time=?, notes=?, room=?, room_style=?, catering=?, tech_equip=?, pre_clean=?, post_clean=?, on_clean=?, reserved_parking=?, vip=? where id=?");
$stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$dptGroup);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$onSiteContact);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$phone);
$stmt->bindParam(5,$email);
$stmt->bindParam(6,$eventDesc);
$stmt->bindParam(7,$setUpTime);
$stmt->bindParam(8,$numOfParticipants);
$stmt->bindParam(9,$date);
$stmt->bindParam(10,$startEndTime);
$stmt->bindParam(11,$specialAcc);
$stmt->bindParam(12,$room);
$stmt->bindParam(13,$roomStyle);
$stmt->bindParam(14,$catering);
$stmt->bindParam(15,$techEquip);
$stmt->bindParam(16,$preClean);
$stmt->bindParam(17,$postClean);
$stmt->bindParam(18,$onClean);
$stmt->bindParam(19,$rsvParking);
$stmt->bindParam(20,$vip);
$stmt->bindParam(21,$id);
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "Success, data updated.";
} else{
    echo "Failed, dated not updated.";
}
} else if($page=='del'){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("delete from reservations where id=?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "Success, data deleted.";
} else{
    echo "Failed to delete data.";
}
} else{
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from reservations order by id desc");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['req_name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dept_group']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['onsite_contact']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phone_num']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_description'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['setup_time']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['num_participants']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['start_end_time']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['notes']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['room']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['room_style']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['catering']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['tech_equip']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pre_clean']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['post_clean']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['on_clean']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['reserved_parking']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['vip']?></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Update</button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="edit-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editLabel-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="editLabel-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Update Data</h4>
                        </div>
                        <form>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name-">Name of Requestor </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['req_name'] ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phone-">Phone Number</label>
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['phone_num'] ?>""  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="setuptime-">Facilities/Catering Set-up time
                                        </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="setuptime-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['setup_time'] ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="dptgroup-">Department/Group</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dptgroup-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['dept_group'] ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email-">Email Address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="partcnum-">Number of Participants</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partcnum-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['num_participants'] ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="onsitecontact-">On-site Contact</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="onsitecontact-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['onsite_contact'] ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="eventdesc-">Description of the Event</label>
                                    <textarea id="eventdesc-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="25" value="<?php echo $row['event_description'] ?>"><?php echo $row['event_description']?></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="date-">Date</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['date'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="startendtime-">Start/End Time (AM/PM)</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startendtime-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['start_end_time'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="specialacc-">Special accommodations, notes or additional requirements</label>
                                    <textarea id="specialacc-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="25" value="<?php echo $row['notes'] ?>"><?php echo $row['notes']?></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="catering-">Is catering needed?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="catering-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['catering'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="techequip-">Is technical equipment needed?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="techequip-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['tech_equip'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="preclean-">Is pre-clean up needed?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="preclean-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['pre_clean'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="onclean-">Is clean up during the event needed?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="onclean-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['on_clean'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="postclean-">Is post clean up needed?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postclean-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['post_clean'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="rsvparking-">Is reserved parking needed?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rsvparking-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['reserved_parking'] ?>"  />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="vip">Will there be a very important person will be in attendance (dignitaries, elected officials, high profile)?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vip-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['vip'] ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" onclick="updateGenData(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="deleteGenData(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)" class="btn btn-danger" style="width: 73.94px; margin-top: 2px">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This is getting pretty unruly. Have you considered using one that's an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) to better organize your database layer?

Comment: You should also submit things from JavaScript as JSON in the `data` section. That will properly encode things and avoids all that ugly string concatenation.

Comment: @tadman To be honest, I didn't even know what those things were until you mentioned it. I'm rather new to php/mySQL, aside from a basic 2 month course and a lot of googling, I have not had much experience.

Comment: @MrLo choose any PHP framework. Symphony, or something lighter https://codecondo.com/minimal-web-frameworks-for-php/

Answer (score 1):

First change ajax `data` section from:

```
data: "name=" + name + "&department=" + dptGroup + "&contact=" + onSiteContact + "&phone="
```

to:

```
data: {"name": name, department: dptGroup , [...]}
```

Second: You will always be doing the js code from the `success` section. If an error occurred, send the error status, eg:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
```

And last: Show yourself error messages. It should define DEBUG constant and depending on the settings display more or less information about the error.

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes and displayed an error message. The issue was naming for the empty fields, some of them had capital letters elsewhere therefore the values weren't updating.